# root of unity, prove relationship

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z^3+1=0$ and $\lambda$ is a complex root, prove that $\lambda^2 + 1 = \lambda$.

I have no idea how to start can someone please help me, I will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it $Z^3-1=0$

Comment: $z^3+1=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)$

Comment: You've asked [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002636/nth-root-of-unity)

Comment: If $n$ is odd, $\forall z\in \mathbb C\left(z^n+1=(z+1)\left(z^{n-1}-z^{n-2}+\ldots +z^2-z+1\right)\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z^3 + 1 = (z+1)(z^2-z+1)$
so the complex root of equation will satisfy the following
$z^2-z+1=0$
$\implies z^2+1=z$ which is the required condition